How to read ArrowArray using DuckDB C-API?
I'm trying to read Apache Arrow arrays using the DuckDB C-API from C++ (that is the recommendation, since the C++ API is considered internal to DuckDB), but I can't seem to get it right.  My attempt looks something like this:
  duckdb_state state;
  duckdb_arrow arrow_result;
  duckdb_arrow_array arrow_array;

  std::cout << "query:" << std::endl;
  state = duckdb_query_arrow(con, "SELECT * FROM test;", &arrow_result);
  // check state
  state = duckdb_query_arrow_array(arrow_result, &arrow_array);
  // check state

However I get a segfault.  Even if I got the above working, it's unclear to me how I would get duck_arrow_array to ArrowArray.
I have put together a minimal example using CMake in this repo.  To compile, do:
git clone git@gist.github.com:53237d649bad9d3d23159bc23adaee44.git duckdb_capi
cd duckdb_capi
cmake -B build -S .
cmake --build build


Works here (on Ubuntu), literally following your steps, i.e., invoking cmake -B build -S . followed by cmake --build build/ and then running the binary:
$ build/main 
query:
ncols: 2
nrows: 3
done!
Array info: len=3, nulls=0, buffers=1, children=2
destroyed!
disconnected!
closed!
$ 

ldd shows it is linked to the libduckdb.so shared library that is part of your cmake setup.
PS As you likely noticed going forward using the ADBC interface may be preferable as what you use here is labeled 'deprecated'.

Strange! I was trying on an ARM machine (Asahi Linux on M1), and it segfaults.  But you are right, I tried on an AMD machine, and it works.  I wonder what is different?  As for the deprecation warning, according to this discussion thread, deprecated doesn't actually mean deprecated! But you are right, maybe using ADBC is a better option.

I don't own M1 hardware but if I had to guess you may be falling victim to some subtle aarch64 <-> amd64 issues.  Not bugs in your setup, but maybe something the duckdb folks need to look at?  Maybe report and issue / discuss on discord?

Good reminder on 'deprecatted' being more of a 'pre-deprecation warning' here.  So yes, as long as it works...
